# spring mvc hibernate proper way of transaction management

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Maybe the title is a little missleading but I'd like to ask you for a piece of advice.

Now let's say I have configured my spring mvc app with hibernate and transactions. Part of configuration looks like this:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl"/>
    <property name="user" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
</bean>
<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.execon.models"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

So basically what I need to do now, is just `@Autowired` my sessinFactory to class which will manage the DB access right?

A quick example, though its with `@Controller`, I'll move it to `@Service` :

```
@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String getMainPage( Model model )
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery( "from Period" );
    List<Period> list = query.list();
    System.out.println( list );
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return "MainPage";
}
```

As you can see I'm just trying to put on std console list of a mapped class. It works great, but I need a piece of advice how this should be managed in bigger project. Should I have some util class which gets session and begin transaction? Or should I use some templates for managing this? Simply I dont want to write this:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    //
    //...
    //
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

In every single place where I need to connect to DB. Maybe I'm missing something, or doing it completly wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit you are missing is the spring transaction annotations.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@Transactional
public String getMainPage( Model model )
{
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(sessionFactory);
    Query query = session.createQuery( "from Period" );
    List<Period> list = query.list();
    System.out.println( list );
    return "MainPage";
}
```

Obviously as you pointed out the normal thing is to separate out the db stuff.

In your context file you will need:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Note in this specific example you will need to put this in the `XXX-servlet.xml` context file because that is the thing that is configuring the controller.

The general idea with spring and hibernate is to use spring for the transaction and connection management. The use of `SessionFactoryUtil` registrators the hibernate Session as a transaction resource bound to the current thread.

Comment: Please tell if I get it right:
1st Q: `@Transactional` with class scope means that EVERY method within this class will be handled with transaction right?
2nd Q: Is it wrong thing that I've done, by making my POJO (Period class) `@Transactional`?
3rd Q: is `getSession()` from package `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3` equal to `openSession()` from package `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4`?

Comment: Q1 yes.. you can set the whole class to transactional... and then refine it on each method. Q2 not particularly wrong.. whole point of spring is to use POJO, it isn't great style to make the methods of a controller transactional, but for a small project, hell if you can test it. Q3 yes it's the same.. sorry didn't pick up on the hibernate4 package name...will update answer